# Numerically robust Cauchy-Schwarz?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is it well-known by [the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) that
$$
\langle x, x\rangle \langle y, y\rangle - \langle x, y\rangle^2 \geq 0
$$
for any $x,y\in H$, $H$ being a Hilbert space with real-valued scalars.

When computing the above expression numerically, sometimes it will be negative (in the order of machine precision) due to round-off errors in the subtraction.

Is there an equivalent expression that is always numerically positive? (E.g., something to the power of 2, a norm of a vector etc.)

Comment: I take it that an absolute value will not suffice? You do know that the quantity is nonnegative, so taking an absolute value will not change its true value, but will result in a nonnegative number on the computer.

Comment: Or taking the maximum of the computed value and 0?

Comment: Would taking the logarithm work? $\log(\langle x, x\rangle )+ \log(\langle y, y\rangle) - 2\log(\langle x, y\rangle) \geq 0$. This help when the numbers get really small and avoids floating point errors because it is addition and subtraction.

Comment: Why do you care?  Is this computation an end in itself, or is it part of a larger computation?

Comment: @RideTheWavelet: taking the absolute value is not the best idea. You know that you are tampering the value, i.e. replacing $-\epsilon$ by $\epsilon$, twice the correction achieved with $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're totally right, I'm not sure what I was thinking the other day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Lagrange's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity):

$$\langle x,x \rangle \langle y,y\rangle - \langle x,y \rangle^2 = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} (x_i y_j - x_j y_i)^2$$

for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.